# SSRS: In a chart group by combining two datasets

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that in the values I have 2 data sets, and then grouping by a location to display the data. If I use the one location within 1 dataset then sure one of the averages I am displaying is perfect but the other is incorrect showing the same result across the board.

No down I need to join these together to get an outcome.

here is what I have:

Values:

```
  1. =Avg(Fields!Rating.Value)
  2. =((sum(Fields!Low_rating.Value,"MIN_MAX_CCR") + sum(Fields!Max_rating.Value, "MIN_MAX_CCR")) / 2 ) / Count(Fields!Case_ID.Value, "MIN_MAX_CCR")
```

Category Grouping:

```
  1.=lookup(Fields!CaseID.Value,Fields!Case_ID.Value, Fields!location.Value,"MIN_MAX_CCR")
```

So the first field is from the current dataset, the second is from the MIN_MAX_CCR dataset, the location is from the first data set, and then getting the data set for the case_ID.

Now when I run this I get this lovely error:
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Group expression for the grouping ‘Chart8_CategoryGroup’ refers to the field ‘location’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.
   at

I just cant see a way around this - I cant combine the data in one query due to the nature of the query differences.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return location from MIN_MAX_CCR, but it doesnt exist.

I would read the documentation or intellisense hints on the Lookup function to learn how to write it correctly.